# Connect to TFS/VSO Agent inside a VPN

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, vpn

I am using Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online), and I have a build agent installed onto a machine inside a VPN.

Is it possible to configure my build in Team Services and have it run using the agent inside my private VPN? If so, how do you connect to the VPN when running a build?

Comment: Is the build machine accessible over https (port 443)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the agent can run anywhere as long as it can access the VSTS instance (it has a public internet connection).

The basic steps are:

- Install the agent on a machine/VM within you network
- Run ConfigureAgent.cmd
- Set the TFS URL to your VSTS url (https://[account].visualstudio.com)
- Provide your creds in the authorization window popup
- You're connected!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/agents/windows